# array_multisort appears sort is incorrect

Tags: php, array-multisort

I have several arrays containing team data... `array_multisort()` appears to not be keeping the team data associations.  I have something like this:

```
Teams[$z] = various strings
ConfNum[$z] = various strings
$DivNum[$z] = various strings
$DivWinner[$z] = integer of 1 or 0.
$TeamRank[$z] = integer of the team's rank
```

for debugging, I use a for loop and print the value of each... so `$Teams[$z] - $ConfNum[$z] - $DivNum[$z]` ... etc.

I run `array_multisort()` (I've used this many times in the past) and suddenly the associations are no longer there.

Here's my debugging.

BEFORE array_multisort:

```
key - Teams - Conf - Div - Rank - DivWin - Series
z:0 -   3 -    2 -   2 -    0  -  1 -      1
z:1 -   10 -   2 -   7 -    8  -  1 -      2
z:2 -   75 -   2 -   2 -    2  -  0 -      3
z:3 -   11 -   2 -   2 -    5  -  0 -      4
z:4 -   55 -   1 -   1 -    1  -  1 -      5
z:5 -   79 -   1 -   6 -    3  -  1 -      6
z:6 -   67 -   1 -   6 -    4  -  0 -      7
z:7 -   4 -    1 -   1 -    6  -  0 -      8
```

Please note z:1...  team 10 should be Conf 2 Div 2 .. etc.  I then run my array_multsort:

```
array_multisort($DivWinner,SORT_DESC,$TeamRank,$Teams,$ConfNum,$DivNum,$SeriesID);
```

This puts my DivWinners at the top, then sorted by my TeamRank.  I include Teams, ConfNum, DivNum, SeriesID as I want to maintain the associations for all those arrays after the sort.

After the sort I get this:

```
key -  Teams - Conf - Div - Rank - DivWin - Series
z:0 -   3 -    2 -    2 -   0  -   1 -      1
z:1 -   10 -   1 -    1 -   1  -   1 -      2
z:2 -   11 -   1 -    6 -   3  -   1 -      4
z:3 -   4 -    2 -    7 -   8  -   1 -      8
z:4 -   75 -   2 -    2 -   2  -   0 -      3
z:5 -   55 -   1 -    6 -   4  -   0 -      5
z:6 -   79 -   2 -    2 -   5  -   0 -      6
z:7 -   67 -   1 -    1 -   6  -   0 -      7
```

So now we go and look at team 10 again.

It's now set to Conf 1 Div 1...  completely incorrect.

It is a DivWinner (set to 1) so it should rank "higher", however, TeamRank is 8... so of the four DivWinners, it should be the lowest... instead it's ranked 2nd.

Comment: `$Teams` is sorted, but `$Team` is printed. typo?

Comment: @Fabricator if you're referring to this part: "Please note z:1... team 10 should be Conf 2 Div 2 " where I say "team", it's not really a typo... just me talking about the Teams variable off-the-cuff.  I've double-checked the code and it is indeed $Teams used in all the examples.

Comment: I'm referring to `for debugging, I use a for loop and print the value of each... so $Team[$z] - $ConfNum[$z] - $DivNum[$z] ... etc.`

Comment: @Fabricator ah, I see. I've double-checked the code and see I'm actually using Teams... so my message was in error (typo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have a bug in the way you're printing out the sorted arrays, here's what I tried and it seems to work.

```
<?php
$Teams = array(3,10,75,11,55,79,67,4);
$ConfNum = array(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1);
$DivNum = array(2,7,2,2,1,6,6,1);
$DivWinner = array(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0);
$rank = array(0,8,2,5,1,3,4,6);
$series = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

array_multisort($DivWinner,SORT_DESC,$Teams,$ConfNum,$DivNum, $rank, $series);


?><table>
<tr>
<th>teams</th>
<th>conf</th>
<th>div</th>
<th>rank</th>
<th>winner</th>
<th>series</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
<?php for($i = 0;$i < count($Teams); $i++):?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $Teams[$i]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $ConfNum[$i]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $DivNum[$i]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rank[$i]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $DivWinner[$i]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $series[$i]?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endfor;?>
```

```
teams conf  div rank  winner  series
3     2     2   0     1       1
10    2     7   8     1       2
55    1     1   1     1       5
79    1     6   3     1       6
4     1     1   6     0       8
11    2     2   5     0       4
67    1     6   4     0       7
75    2     2   2     0       3
```

OR maybe your code is bugged somewhere else.

Comment: I had another look at print_r of each array... they were in the order as they had been entered, so key 1, 4, 2, etc...  not 1, 2, 3... Seems I needed to do a ksort before the array_multisort (as i've indicated in my answer below). Thanks for making me check the code again. :)

Answer (score 1):

So...  I had been creating the arrays based on the key associated from the $Teams array...  I look up the ConfNum, DivNum, etc for $Teams[$z] and insert it into the $ConfNum[$z] array.

I decided to print_r on all the arrays right before I performed the array_multisort... lo and behold, each array printed in a different order (as they were created / added). So for team 10 (which was the 2nd Team in the list), the second ConfNum was indeed 1, even though the key $z was for another team.

When I performed array_multisort, it did not take into account the keys, instead it sorted based on the order the values were added to each array.

I was able to correct this problem by performing ksort() on all the arrays before I started on with array_multisort.

Doing this definitely corrected my problem... all the arrays seem to be reporting the correct numbers and in the correct order.

Thank you to everyone that took a little time to think about my problem.